# Alternative for Timers

Tags: swift, timer

I am having a simple game with a player, a moving background and moving walls, kinda like flappy bird. My player is able to collect a powerUp. It is transforming after and put into a special level.

I want this level to run for like 10 seconds and then call a backtransformation.

Currently I am using a timer which just calls the backtransformation after 10 seconds. I am having trouble now when the player pauses the game, the timer is still running.

--> what I found on stackoverflow is that you can't resume a timer, you can just invalidate and restart it. This would miss my target, otherwise the player pauses the game every 9 seconds and can stay in the super Level forever.

Do you guys have any idea how I can solve my problem or like an alternative to use Timers in my code?

I appreciate any help

Edit: Here is how I simply used the timer

```
// transform and go into super level added here
self.transform()

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:10, repeats: false) {
                    timer in
self.backtransform()
}
```

Comment: you can try setting the time interval of the timer to 1 second, and use a variable as an incremental count or something.

Comment: Why don't you just do the back transformation if the user pauses the game? I do a similar thing in my game; if the user tries to pause things while the timer is running, I immediately throw away the timer and treat it as having run out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the timer record the current time as a Double using

```
let start = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
var remaining = 10.0
```

When the user pauses the timer, calculate the amount of time that has passed with:

```
let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - start
```

And the amount of remaining time for your timer:

```
remaining -= elapsed
```

If the user resumes the timer, set it to remaining, not 10 seconds.